# Servlets + JSP leading to response 404 and server error "PWC6117"

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, glassfish

I am just a beginner in Java Web and I am exploring the pure Servlets and JSPs (with no frameworks). I am trying to build up a simple CRUD and I got stuck in an error that makes no sense at all (at least to me!).

#### Objective

I wanna build a simple CRUD with several Servlets containing the logics and database operations (*controller*) and JSPs to display the pages (*views*). I have already successfully build up a `CustomerIndexServlet` (route: **/customers**), which returns the list of records and a button to `CustomerNewServlet` (route: **/customers/new**) which SHOULD return a JSP with the form to create new records.

#### Issue

Calling `CustomerNewServlet` leads to a **Page Not Found (404)** and GlassFish prints the message *PWC6117: File "null" not found* in the console. By debugging the code, the error occurs when forwarding the request through `RequestDispatcher`. I don't understand! If I try to access the JSP directly (at http://localhost:8080/MyApp/customerForm.jsp), it returns OK (200). I even printed the path of JSP before forwarding to make sure it is the one expected!

```
@WebServlet(name = "NewCustomer", urlPatterns = {"/customers/new"})
public class NewCustomerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println(request.getContextPath());
        if (request.getSession().getAttribute("login") == null)
/*error*/   request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getContextPath()).forward(request, response);
        else
/*error*/   request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getContextPath() + "/customerForm").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

And in server's console it is displayed:

```
Info:   /MyApp
Server: PWC6117: File "null" not found
```

What am I doing wrong? Does it have something to do with the file locations and directories?

Comment: You're of course free to "explore pure Servlets", but _nobody_ uses them anymore (and newer systems are even starting to get away from Servlets entirely). I encourage you not to worry about it any more than you worry about manually handling HTTP parsing.

Comment: @skomisa Without knowing more than that they exist and that the Filter design pattern exists, yes, absolutely. Spring MVC and Dropwizard abstract the Servlet API away essentially completely, and newer approaches like Spring Webflux don't use Servlets at all.

Comment: Which version of Glassfish are you using?

Comment: 1. Please share the code for /customers jsp. which has button to route /customers/new

Comment: 1. Please share the code for /customers jsp. which has button to route /customers/new 2. is System.out.println(request.getContextPath()); in NewCustomerServlet  is printing

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what happen and how redirection and forward deal with URI's... I'm gonna share the knowledge I've acquired:

#### response.sendRedirect(`URL`)

When using the `sendRedirect()` method, you are  requesting the client to submit a new request to the passed URL. When using an absolute path, you have to concatenate the `request.getContextPath()` prefix to your URL, if you wanna target a resource within your application.

#### request.getRequestDispatcher(`URL`).forward(...)

When dispatching the request to another URL, it already uses application context. So using `request.getContextPath() + "/customerForm.jsp"` as target URL will only look for a resource in **/AppName/AppName/customerForm.jsp**. Then, omitting the `getContextPath()` call is enough to make my code work as expected.